# Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.util.UUID]

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a table in Cassandra which I am trying to iterate and extract stuff from it. I am using datastax java driver 3.1.0.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  client_id int,
  process_id text,
  last_modified_date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY ((client_id), process_id)
)
```

Below is the code:

```
private List<MetaHolder> getMetaHolder() {
    List<MetaHolder> metaHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from test where client_id=1";
    try {
      BoundStatement bs = Cache.getInstance().getStatement(sql);
      bs.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);

      ResultSet res = session.execute(bs);
      Iterator<Row> rows = res.iterator();
      while (rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rows.next();
        String processId = row.getString("PROCESS_ID");
        // this line throws exception
        UUID lastModifiedDate = row.getUUID("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE");
        MetaHolder metadata =
            new MetaHolder(processId, lastModifiedDate);
        metaHolder.add(metadata);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
    return metaHolder;
}
```

Below is the exception:

```
error= com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.util.UUID]
```

Is there any way I can use JodaTime by creating a codec if possible instead of using UUID here in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below code

```
UUID lastModifiedDate = row.getUUID("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE");
```

to

```
Date lastModifiedDate = row.getTimestamp("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE");
```

You can get joda DateTime from Date

```
DateTime lastModifiedDateTime = new DateTime(lastModifiedDate);
```

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from LocalDate to Date`. I tried that already and this is the error I was getting. Also I wanted to use JodaTime here so looks like I can do it by creating a codec but not sure how..

Comment: Yeah but my question was also how can I use JodaTime instead of taking it as Date. I was reading [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/extras/) but didn;t quite follow.